# Apt seems to be corrupt?

Tags: raspbian, apt

If I do 'apt update' or any other apt command, the terminal screen is cleared and

`ist9DepRemovEEN8pkgCache11DepIteratorE, version APTPKG_5.0`

is printed. I've tried to reinstall apt using wget

```
 wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.8.2.2_armhf.deb
```

and it seems to be successful, but there's no change :-(

Comment: `wget` just downloads a package. Install `.deb`-packages via `dpkg -i package.deb`. However maybe try `apt install --fix-broken` first.

Comment: thanks @Fiximan ! Sorry I should have said I then did dpkg -i apt_1.8.2.2_armhf.deb and it went through all the updating triggers etc, but the net result is the same. Doing apt install --fix-broken just gives the same result - a flicker then a screen clear then it says ist9DepRemovEEN8pkgCache11DepIteratorE, version APTPKG_5.0

Comment: wahoooo - reinstalling libapt-pkg5.0_1.8.2.2_armhf.deb did the trick!! I think it got corrupted by node-red when I was adding to the pallet... THANK YOU

Comment: Nice to hear. Please make your solution an answer, so others may profit of it.

Comment: apparently I can accept my answer in two days. Good old stackexchange! Lol

Answer (score 5):

reinstalling libapt-pkg5.0_1.8.2.2_armhf.deb did the trick!!